# VB Running grouped LINQ into DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to run a LINQ to datatable, that normally works for me.  This time I'm trying something new to me, Grouping and taking the first row from each group. questionGroups is of type IEnumerable(Of Object). When I open the query in the debugger I see a collection of DataRows, each with an ItemArray of the values I expect in the columns. How do I run this query to a DataTable, or select the two columns I want and run those into a Dictionary?

> Public member 'ToTable' on type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator(Of
>   VB$AnonymousType_0(Of Object,IEnumerable(Of Object)),Object)' not
>   found.

```
    Dim answerGroup As String = "QuestionSortKey"
    Dim answerNo As String = "AnswerNo"
    Dim surveyDefinitionNo As String = "Pk_SurveyDefinitionNo"

    Dim query = _
        From rows In surveyAnswerKeys.Rows _
        Where rows(answerNo) IsNot Nothing _
        Order By Guid.NewGuid() _
        Group By questionSortKey = rows(answerGroup) _
        Into questionGroups = Group _
        Select questionGroups.First()


    Dim randomAnswerNos As DataTable = query.ToTable
```

Edit: This question is an offshoot of this one: [VB LINQ - Take one random row from each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899264/vb-linq-take-one-random-row-from-each-group)